# How to retrieve 10 latest DISTINCT IP's from a MySQL table?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table containing pagehit (normalized) data and I need to grab the 10 latest unique ips.

I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM spy_hits ORDER BY date desc GROUP BY ip LIMIT 10;
```

Which should give me this result:

```
+-----+------------+-----+---------+----+------+------+---------+-------+-------+
| id  | date       | ip  | browser | os | page | host | referer | query | agent |
+-----+------------+-----+---------+----+------+------+---------+-------+-------+
| 354 | 1244442065 |   2 |       3 |  2 |   16 |    1 |      47 |    12 |     2 |
| 311 | 1244442000 |   1 |       2 |  1 |   16 |    1 |      36 |    12 |     1 |
+-----+------------+-----+---------+----+------+------+---------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That is the latest unique visitors to the site.

But I get a syntax error instead of that result.

So I have to do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM spy_hits GROUP BY ip ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 10;
```

Which I thought would be ok.  But it gives this result:

```
+-----+------------+-----+---------+----+------+------+---------+-------+-------+
| id  | date       | ip  | browser | os | page | host | referer | query | agent |
+-----+------------+-----+---------+----+------+------+---------+-------+-------+
| 280 | 1242130841 |   2 |       3 |  2 |   16 |    1 |      47 |    12 |     2 |
| 268 | 1242130818 |   1 |       2 |  1 |   16 |    1 |      36 |    12 |     1 |
+-----+------------+-----+---------+----+------+------+---------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But that sets order by date after its grouped already so it grabs the first unique ips in the table which are also the oldest.

So the table goes:

```
 id --- date
 268    1242130818    (Old)
  |      |
  V      V
 354    1244442065    (New)
```

But I want it to go like this before I do the group by:

```
 id --- date
 354    1244442065    (New)
  ^       ^
  |       |
 268    1242130818    (Old)
```

I'm using PHP with it so if anyone has an idea of how to get the results with a PHP solution.

Cheers in advance :)

Comment: +1 for a solid question from a relatively new user. If all questions in StackOverflow were like this the world would be a better place.

Comment: +1 for the same reason of the above comment. Keep it up! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have few `DISTINCT IP`'s:

```
SELECT  ip, MAX(date) AS maxdate
FROM    (
        SELECT  ip, MAX(date) AS maxdate
        FROM    spy_hits
        GROUP BY
                ip
        )
ORDER BY
        maxdate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you have lots of `DISTINCT IP`'s:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    spy_hits so
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    spy_hits si
        WHERE   si.ip = so.ip
                AND si.date > so.date
        )
ORDER BY
        date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Creating two indexes on this table:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_spyhits_date ON spy_hits (date)
CREATE INDEX ix_spyhits_ip_date ON spy_hits (ip, date)
```

will improve these queries a lot.

See this entry in my blog for performance details:

- [**Latest DISTINCT records**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/08/latest-distinct-records/)